# Delphi creating thread safe writing functions

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi XE in order to create a multi thread application.

I want to create a thread to handle all the writing into a firebird/sqlite database log.
And i want to create several threads that do some jobs and these other threads need to use the writing log thread when they need.

```
Thread1 = writing log thread  
Thread2 = do some math and from time to time use Thread1 to write log.  
Thread3 = do some other stuff and from time to time use Thread1 to write log.
```

and so on

for simplicity I have created a method in thread1 named WriteCollectionLog that all the other thread need to use to write the log into thread1 memory (a collection) and thread1 "onexecute" will handle the real log write into the database. This method is intended to be used like a "fire and forget" method.

now how do i make this thread safe? or can I make it thread safe? (by using TCriticalSection?)

```
thread2.WriteCollectionLog ...
thread3.WriteCollectionLog ...

procedure Thread1.WriteCollectionLog(aIDWORKFLOW : Integer);
var workItem : TLogFIREBIRD_Item;
begin
  try
    readWriteCriticalSection.Acquire;  <--- this will suspend the calling thread .. like thread2, thread3 and not the thread1?
    do stuff;
  finally
    readWriteCriticalSection.Release;
  end;
end;
```

Regards
Razvan

Comment: Store the log items into a queue (thread safe one) and let the thread pool handle its content.

Answer (score 0):

Just implement what you wrote: only write to the DB from Thread1.

Please don't expect to "call" one thread from another, as you may using "Synchronize" to run some code in the main thread. It would be blocking, which is not what you expect, I guess.

The idea is to have a small in-memory structure, shared between the threads, protected by a critical section. One goal is to keep any critical section as small as possible.

For instance, you may use a `TObjectQueue`, then Thread2 and Thread3 will push some data to the queue, and Thread1 will wait for some pending data in the Queue, then unqueue it and write it - and if you define a transaction, it will be faster than a naive blocking process. If you just want to write some log content, use a `TArray<string>`, with an associated lock.